# Remove last value in a string

Tags: php

```
<?php    
    $values = "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,";//Remove last comma
    $values = "aaa,bbb,,,";//Remove all commas after bbb like aaa,bbb
?>
```

How to remove commas in this example

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question, these aren't array elements, none the less, what have you tried?

Comment: First of all this is not an array. You need to trim these `,`...

Answer (score 1):

You can trim "," using the below code: use php function [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php).

```
<?php    

$values = "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,";//Remove last comma
echo rtrim($values,',');
echo "<br/>";

$values = "aaa,bbb,,,";//Remove all commas before bbb like aaa,bbb
echo rtrim($values,',');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `trim()` function of PHP.

```
echo $values = trim("aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,",',');  // aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
echo $values = trim("aaa,bbb,,,",',');        // aaa,bbb
```

Second parameter of `trim()` indicates the character to be deleted.